# Vulkan depth buffer position reconstruction

Tags: graphics, rendering, shader, vulkan

I am reconstructing position for a stencil light shader.
This means i have vertices for the spherical approximation of the light from which i can get a world space view vector (vertexPos - cameraPos). The code looks like this:

```
vec3 construct_pos_ws(float depthBufferZ)
{
    vec3 viewRay = normalize(gInVert.vRayWs);
    float viewZDist = dot(gInFrame.eyeZAxis, viewRay);
    vec3 relPoint = viewRay * linearDepth(depthBufferZ) / viewZDist;
    return gInFrame.eye + relPoint;
}
```

vRayWs : world space view ray (interpolating vertexPos - cameraPos in the vertexshader) 
eyeZAxis : world space z axis of the eye (camera direction)
viewZDist : the depth buffer holds a distance parallel to the camera surface, but we need a distance, this accounts for the angle at which we view the object.

---

The problem is with the linearization function I use, based on [wikipedia: z-buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering):
(I leave out the S = 2^d-1, this parts seems to not apply).

```
float linearDepth(float z_b) {
    float f = z_far;
    float n = z_near;
    return (-f * n / (z_b (f - n) - f));
}
```

This does not work, but using `float n = z_near * 2` instead gives (seemingly) correct results (which i just randomly tried, since the previous answer looked close to correct).

---

I've tried other linearization as well, using inverses of all the tree variants on the wikipedia page (the 3 below), but none worked.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

---

**Actual question:**
So what is going on? Why does multiplication by 2 seem to give a correct answer? And what formula does vulkan use to write to the depth buffer, since it does not seem to use any of the formulas on wikipedia?

---

Finally, for completeness, the projection matrix construction is like this:

```
float yScale = 1.0f / tan(fov / 2.0f);
float xScale = yScale / aspect;
float nearmfar = z_near - z_far;
Matrix m = {
    xScale, 0, 0, 0,
    0, yScale, 0, 0,
    0, 0, (z_far + z_near) / nearmfar, -1,
    0, 0, 2 * z_far * z_near / nearmfar, 0
};
```

Also, how do I know it is correct:

Using the change, and rendering "position mod 1" gives the first image (stable while moving the camera), while the original function gives the second picture (very unstable when moving the camera).

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd have to double check but I guess that it's because the Z of the NDC goes from 0 to 1 instead of -1 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan uses a depth range of [0, 1] (and actually also flipped the Y axis), instead of OpenGL's [-1, 1]. You have two options to get OpenGL-like behaviour:

- fix the NDC Z in the shader to conform to the OpenGL way, as you do at the moment by multiplying by two
- or premultiply your projection matrix with the matrix

  `1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  0.0   -1.0  0.0   0.0
  0.0   0.0   0.5   0.5
  0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0`

Have a look at https://matthewwellings.com/blog/the-new-vulkan-coordinate-system/ for more details. The Vulkan specification (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/html/vkspec.html#vertexpostproc-clipping) also has more details, though not stated as clearly.

Comment: Thank you, his helps a lot for clarification, but there is some weird problem still going on. Using that matrix without the negation at [1,1] does work but then gives inverted y. However with that negation I cannot produce any results, the screen stays black, as if everything is always discarded.

Comment: Is your camera maybe just facing in the wrong direction then? Also, somewhat related, baldurk's renderdoc (https://renderdoc.org) is an absolutely awesome tool to debug such problems. Maybe it can help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ill have a look at that, and until I figure out the upside down problem out i can just point my up vector downwards and then it works too.